# How to get full exception stacktrace when using await() on CompletableFuture

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

### Problem

I am using `kotlinx.coroutines.future.FutureKt#await` to await for an async code. But when any exception is thrown from this async code, the Exception doesn't contain full stack call. E.g.:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    try {
        myFun1Blocking()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out)
    }
}

fun myFun1Blocking() {
    runBlocking {
        myFun2Suspend()
    }
}

suspend fun myFun2Suspend() {
    runAsync().await()
}

fun runAsync(): CompletableFuture<Void> {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        throw Exception()
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at TestKotlinKt.runAsync$lambda-0(TestKotlin.kt:34)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

The stack trace only has the `runAsync` method part.

### Solution #1

While trying to workaround this problem, I first thought of catching it just outside of await:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> CompletionStage<T>.awaitWithException(): T {
    try {
        return await()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw Exception(e)
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception
    at TestKotlinKt.awaitWithException(TestKotlin.kt:36)
    at TestKotlinKt$awaitWithException$1.invokeSuspend(TestKotlin.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at TestKotlinKt.myFun1Blocking(TestKotlin.kt:23)
    at TestKotlinKt.main(TestKotlin.kt:16)
    at TestKotlinKt.main(TestKotlin.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at TestKotlinKt.runAsync$lambda-0(TestKotlin.kt:43)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Better, but I still lost the myFun2Suspend call in the stack.

### Solution #2

Then I tried saving the stacktrace just before await():

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> CompletionStage<T>.awaitWithException(printStream: PrintStream): T {
    val throwable = Throwable("Await Exception")
    try {
        return await()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throwable.printStackTrace(printStream)
        throw e
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.Throwable: Await Exception
    at TestKotlinKt.awaitWithException(TestKotlin.kt:43)
    at TestKotlinKt.myFun2Suspend(TestKotlin.kt:31)
    at TestKotlinKt$myFun1Blocking$1.invokeSuspend(TestKotlin.kt:26)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at TestKotlinKt.myFun1Blocking(TestKotlin.kt:25)
    at TestKotlinKt.main(TestKotlin.kt:18)
    at TestKotlinKt.main(TestKotlin.kt)
AsyncException
    at TestKotlinKt.runAsync$lambda-0(TestKotlin.kt:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Now I see everything.

All in all, my solution seems to be very hacky. Is there something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [Kotlin's documentation about debugging](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/topics/debugging.md) both of your solutions have officially supported counterparts:

- Set the system property `kotlinx.coroutines.debug` to `on` to enable debug mode. This enables stacktrace recovery which is a more comprehensive version of solution #1.
- Use the [Kotlin debug agent](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-debug/README.md) to enable creation stacktraces which is the official version of solution #2. Do be aware that this is a very expensive feature because it will need to dump stack traces each time a coroutine is created.

In theory kotlin debug mode should be enough since the exception has to unwind through the 'stack' of coroutines. It just isn't the prettiest solution.

Comment: What should be done for catching full stacktrace on production? I suppose I shouldnt have debug mode enabled on production.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. The Kotlin coroutine debug library didn't help me in any way.
Therefore, after studying the implementation of coroutines, I wrote my own solution based on bytecode generation and MethodHandle API. It supports JVM 1.8 and Android API 25 or higher.
I called it [Stacktrace-decoroutinator](https://github.com/Anamorphosee/stacktrace-decoroutinator).

The reason why the stacktrace is lost is that when the coroutine wakes up, only the last method of its call stack is called.

My library replaces the coroutine awakening implementation. It generates classes at runtime with names that match the entire coroutine call stack.

These classes don't do anything except call each other in the coroutine call stack sequence.

Thus, if the coroutine throws an exception, they mimic the real call stack of the coroutine during the creation of the exception  stacktrace.

Comment: I think this still misses the explanation of *how* you did it and only provides a description of *what* you did. Without the "how", this still is not really more than a link to your own work and still/again risks being deleted.